# Install Ubuntu 19.04 in Dell Gaming I5 5577

Tags: boot, nvidia-geforce

Good day,

I have a problem installing the Linux operating system Ubuntu on my computer Dell Gaming I5 5577 I would like to know if they have any solution, it seems to be the drivers of the dedicated Nvidia GTX 1050 TI card.

Regards,

Comment: Yes, you need to install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: When I install Ubuntu everything goes very well, when I restart it after the installation is stuck, is there a repository where I can get compatible drivers with this video card?

Comment: You need an additional boot parameter: `nomodeset` -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu . Then you'll boot in low graphics mode, allowing g you to open Software & Updates > Additional Drivers where you can select and apply the recommended version.

Comment: Received, thank you very much, I will try with that parameter